# How to understand and unit test this React-Redux function with Jest

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs

*I'm new to React & Redux* and I have several functions in a module which I'm working on,

```
function showDialogAction(): Action {
    return {
        type : SHOW_DIALOG
    };
}

function showDialog() { 
    return (dispatch : (action : Action) => void) => {
        dispatch(showDialogAction());
    };
}
```

Now I need to write a unit test for `showDialog()` function. Still I'm having a hard time understanding what it exactly does. Is it `returning a function that accepts Action and returns void ?? Or ...`

Really appreciate if anyone can explain how it works and any suggestions to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns a function that gets the `dispatch` function as an parameter and calls it with the result of `showDialogAction`.

So in forms of the types `dispatch : (action : Action) => void`, there is `dispatch` which is a function `()=>` that get a parameter `action` that is from type `Action` (`action : Action`) and that returns nothing (`void`)

The easiest way to test this is using a spy for `dispatch`:

```
const dispatch = jest.fn()
showDialog()(dispatch) 
expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({type : 'SHOW_DIALOG'})
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Can you please explain what is  `dispatch : (action : Action) => void`, Why there is `action : Action` ? May be update the answer

Comment: Updated with a explanation of the type